# PMTimeActivity Usr Fields

Tags: acumatica

I'm lost and not sure I am going about this the right way.
I have placed a PXAction Button on the EP305000 screen.

[EP305000 Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIe10.png)

When the button is pressed I wanted to search for any records in the PMTimeActivity table for the current user that has the UsrPIXIClockIn NOT null AND the UsrPIXIClockOut Null.
If found, need to set its value to the current time.  If not found then create a new record with the UsrPIXIClockIn field set to the current time.

However, my first attempt of just trying to read the Usr fields is creating an error.  When I try to parse a PXResultSet, code lines containing my Usr Fields are throwing an error when compiling.
There error is: 'PX.Objects.CR.PMTimeActivity' does not contain a definition for 'UsrPIXIClockIn' and no extension method 'UsrPIXIClockIn' accepting a first argument of type 'PX.Objects.CR.PMTimeActivity'

I am not sure where this definition belongs or how to define it.  Here is the Code I have:

```
  [Serializable]
  public class PMTimeActivityExt : PXCacheExtension<PMTimeActivity>
  {    
    public PXSelect<PMTimeActivity> PMTimeActivity;  

    #region UsrPIXIClockIn
    [PXDBTime(DisplayMask = "t", UseTimeZone = false)]
    [PXUIField (DisplayName="Clock In")]
    public virtual DateTime? UsrPIXIClockIn { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrPIXIClockIn : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrPIXIClockOut
    [PXDBTime(DisplayMask = "t", UseTimeZone = false)]
    [PXUIField (DisplayName="Clock Out")]
    public virtual DateTime? UsrPIXIClockOut { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrPIXIClockOut : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrPIXITotalHours
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXUIField (DisplayName="Total Hours")]
    public virtual decimal? UsrPIXITotalHours { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrPIXITotalHours : IBqlField { }
    #endregion                       

  }

  public class TimeCardMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<TimeCardMaint>
  {    
    public PXSelect<PMTimeActivity> PMTimeActivity;
    public PXAction<EPTimeCard> PunchCard;

    public PXAction<PX.Objects.EP.EPTimeCard> PunchTimeCard;  

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Punch Time Card")]
    protected void punchTimeCard(PXCache cache)
    {            
      System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
      sb.AppendLine("Started...\n");
      EPEmployee employeeByUserID = PXSelect<EPEmployee, Where<EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<Current<EPTimeCard.employeeID>>>>.Select(this.Base);
      Guid userID = (Guid) employeeByUserID.UserID;
      sb.AppendLine("user ID:" + userID.ToString() + "\n");

      // This one returns all records.
      PXResultset<PMTimeActivity> TimeActivity = PXSelect<PMTimeActivity>.Select(this.Base);

      foreach (PMTimeActivity timeRecord in TimeActivity)
      {                  
          if (timeRecord.OwnerID == userID) {
                      sb.AppendLine("UsrPIXIClockIn:" + timeRecord.UsrPIXIClockIn + "\n");                
          }          
      }

      sb.AppendLine("\nEnded...\n");
      throw new PXException("Clicked Punch Time Card!\n" + sb.ToString());
    }

  }
```

As for the PXSelect for the PXResultSet I tried this:

```
PXResultset<PMTimeActivity> TimeActivity = PXSelect<PMTimeActivity, Where<Required<PMTimeActivity.ownerID>, Equal<Current<PMTimeActivity.ownerID>>>>.Select(this.Base, userID);
```

But no records are ever found.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message boils down to: PMTimeActivity does not contain UsrPIXIClockIn.

`PMTimeActivity` is the base DAC and the user fields are in the extended DAC `PMTimeActivityExt`.

You need to fetch the extension from the base DAC first using `GetExtension` method and access your user field on the extension record `timeRecordExt.UsrPIXIClockIn`:

```
  foreach (PMTimeActivity timeRecord in TimeActivity)
  {
      PMTimeActivityExt timeRecordExt = timeRecord.GetExtension<PMTimeActivityExt>();

      if (timeRecordExt != null && timeRecord.OwnerID == userID) {
         sb.AppendLine("UsrPIXIClockIn:" + timeRecordExt.UsrPIXIClockIn + "\n");                
      }          
  }
```

In your question I see there's a data view declaration in the DAC extension. Maybe that's a typo, you should remove it as DAC extension should only contain user fields. This is important because Acumatica aggressively parses these code structures. So remove that line from PMTimeActivityExt class:

```
public PXSelect<PMTimeActivity> PMTimeActivity;
```

Comment: When the foreach loop itterates, nothing shows for the UsrPIXIClockIn.  These are datetime fields.  Do I need to do something special to get the value.  Looking through Source Code and T?00 Course manuals I am not finding what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing shows? That seem a bit too broad a problem.

Comment: To get the value is like any C# nullable field, timeRecordExt.UsrPIXIClockIn.Value